# kexec: is initrd fully pinned in memory or still backed by storage?

Tags: kexec

I have an embedded system booting on an eMMC, and I would like an easy way to flash the whole eMMC over ssh, without having to rely on PXE boot or things like that, for pratical reasons.

I can easily drop a new kernel and a new initrd CPIO containing a whole rootfs on my `/` partition, and then just after do:

```
kexec -l /home/root/bzImage --initrd=/home/root/initrd.cpio.gz
systemctl kexec
```

It works as expected, I loose my SSH connection after the `systemctl kexec` and can log in a few seconds later to the new "live" system.

I see `mount` outputing:

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw,size=3913004k,nr_inodes=978251,inode64)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=4096k,nr_inodes=131072,mode=755,inode64)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=1595352k,nr_inodes=819200,mode=755,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
```

So it seems that everything is in RAM, and that I can now safely do things like `dd if=stuff.img of=/dev/mmcblk0`, changing and formatting new partitions, etc.

However when looking at `free -m` output, I see:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            7789          89        7217         473         483        7158
Swap:              0           0           0
```

I'm confused about the `used` value, I expect it to be at least the size of my full uncompressed live rootfs (~ 500 Mb). Is it the thing tagged as `shared` instead?

Is it safe to write directly on my eMMC in this state?

EDIT:

I just realised that what is loaded in memory is the gzipped CPIO, which is then later uncompressed by the next kernel. So, after the `kexec`, everything is obviously in memory and the original file on the eMMC does not matter anymore.

What I guess now is that this volatile rootfs is actually considered as `tmpfs`, which is reported as `shared` by the `free` utility.

Am I correct?